# How to access a variable outside of an API request function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm struggling to access the currrentPrice variable outside of this API call. How is it done?

```
var currentPrice
//Get the curent market price
var marketSymobl = checkOrders[i].symbol.split(" - ")[0].toUpperCase()
console.log(checkOrders[i].symbol)
finnhubClient.quote(marketSymobl, (error, data, response) => {
  currentPrice = data.c

});

console.log(currentPrice)
```

Comment: You can't. The API call runs asynchronously, you can only access the variable in code that runs after the response is received.

Comment: Hi Barmar. Thank you very much for you valuable input. Is there no way to access the data from the request outside of it?

Comment: You can access it later, but not immediately after sending the request.

Comment: Think of it like this: You order something from Amazon.com. If you then go to your doorstep, there won't be anything there. But if you wait a day or so, it will be there.